# Blazor - Directly accessing page URL does not work, on click via NavMenu works

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, mudblazor

I have 2 components:

- Blazor
- Test

For the Blazor component, I can access via the NavMenu or directly via browser without issues.
URL: `https://localhost:5000/blazor`

For the Test component, I can access via the NavMenu, but it will show a **blank page** if directly accessing via the browser (Developer Tools show a **404 error**)
URL: `https://localhost:5000/test`

The only difference is that "blazor" component is specified as the `@page` in the `_Host.cshtml` file.

Here is the `Test.Razor` file

[image]

Here is the `_Host.cshtml` file

[image]

Comment: Post code using StackOverflow code sections instead of images.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand Blazor Server correctly, your `_Host.cshtml` needs to stay on "/" page path, as it is the actual page rooted to load your razor components, as also reference for URL navigation, but you can also gives it multiple `@page` attribute, so it would respond/shown from multiple URL.

As for why it is returns 404 when accessed directly via URL but not when with `NavMenu`, when you hit "/blazor" first, all of your razor components (.razor files with or with without `@page` attribute) get discovered, your app 'session' start and whenever you navigate through `NavMenu` or built-in C# component like `NavigationManager` the 'session' persist. But whenever you hit the URL directly, your browser ask directly for that specific path, skipping the page in "/blazor" path that actually do the `@page`s discovery then load the internal navigation mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case that this is still open: I have managed to get it up and running by adding a fallback page. This can be done by adding the following to the `Startup.cs`:

```cs
app.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");
```